# how am I suppose to remotely delete my google account on a device that is accessing a specific app

Tags: applications, google-apps, clash-of-clans

I recently added my account on a device so he could access my game app whick is the Clash of Clans (COC)

now that person is controlling my COC using his device and cursing my clann mates via coc chat..

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Google.com or any Google site.
2. Sign into the account you're referring to, if you're not already signed in.
3. Click the circle avatar or photo (a blue person by default) in the very top right corner of the page.
4. Click "Account".
5. Under "Recent Activity", click "Devices".
6. Click the device you're referring to.
7. There should be a big red "Remove" button next to the words "Account access" under this device once you have clicked the device.  Click this button.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are concerned about your Google account being used from other devices or being used by someone else, just check [your security settings](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity?pli=1) and follow the on-screen instructions to log them off.
- If you are concerned about third-party applications (to which you might have previously authorized) still having access to your account, you can individually revoke their access from [Google security](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions).
- If you want to completely erase data (apps, contacts, mail, etc.) from a device you have lost, you can do that from [device manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager).